# Make ClassMethods also available as module function with ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

Given the following code:

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

What I'd like to do is call `Foo.foo` instead of `Bar.foo`. Sometimes it feels more natural to call a class method on the original module, especially when the functionality has nothing to do with the included class and is better described along with the original module name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a code smell. Having said that, you can just have the Foo module extend itself with the class methods:

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end
  end

  extend ClassMethods
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.foo
Foo.foo
```

Comment: It works great, thanks! BTW why do you think the code smells?

Comment: Having a module extend itself from a module that is defined as its class methods just doesn't seem right. Normally if you wanted to access the foo method from Foo, you would just do `Foo::ClassMethods.foo`. There's nothing "wrong" with it, but it's not a pattern I've ever seen before and wouldn't recommend getting in the habit of it.

Comment: @Beerlington: Are you sure that this works `Foo::ClassMethods.foo` on the first example? I've just tested and it didn't (Ruby v2.0). Thanks.